# Neutrino-Nucleus quasielastic scattering

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos

Concerning the quasielastic charged-current interactions of neutrinos deep underground, the production of muons from interactions with nuclei is of importance to neutrino telescopes.

In the calculations of the muon flux, Edsjö & Gondolo[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9504283v1) (hep-ph 9504283) describe a Gaussian angular distribution and gives the rms value of the distribution in terms of incoming neutrino energy.

> $\theta^{rms}_{CC} ≃ \frac{19 ^\circ}{\sqrt{E_\nu}}$

I want to understand how the distribution is obtained. Any recent literature with more information will help too.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the references in the paper? This would be the first course in going through any academic paper. Also instead of just looking a paper using a number consider spelling out the name of the paper and primary author(s) in case the link doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, that should say linking and not looking.

Comment: Of course I went through the references, but didn't make a lot of progress. The authors simply state that they got the results by simulation in PYTHIA without more details.

Comment: what are the units of $E_{\nu}$?

Comment: $E_{\nu}$ is in GeV

Answer (score 0):

The paper explains they modeled 3 contributions to the angular distribution: detector resolution, Coulomb multiple scattering of the muon, and of course the CC interaction via PYTHIA.

At these energies, the process would be charged-current (CC) deep inelastic scattering (DIS) from nuclei, that is scattering from quarks and antiquarks in the nuclei. That is what PYTHIA does, so check the documentation there.

Maybe a MINERvA reverence helps:

https://mod.fnal.gov/mod/w1/Lectures/NP2016/presentations/160614Wospakrik.pdf